# Replace HTML Hyperlink Text on Javacscript Form Submit Button

Tags: javascript, html, send

I have a HTML button to submit a form with form validation using javascript -

```
<p class="textstyle1"><a href="javascript:document.contact.submit();"><span onClick="MM_validateForm('Name','','R','Email','','RisEmail','Message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">Send</span></a></p>
```

When the form is submitted, I want the button text to change from "Send" to "Please Wait..." while the php code runs which emails the user and inserts the form data into a MySQL database.

I've done a lot of research and found code to change the text for an actual Submit button but I would like help with code to change the HTML hyperlink text instead.

Comment: Intrinsic event handler attributes? Links with JavaScript instead of submit buttons? Macromedia written JavaScript functions? Passing data by hanging it off `document` instead of `return`ing it? I think I want to curl up and cry.

Answer (score 0):

But here you are submitting the form using normal postback. So, when user clicks on "Send", page will postback and server side code i.e, send email and database insertions gets executed. If it is AJAX page, after user clicks on submit link, then innerHTML property of the link can be changed to "Please wait" and after receiving response from server, change back to "Send".

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use a hyperlink `<a>` - use a submit button and style it to look like a hyperlink, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/W9xQU/).

Next, define a JavaScript event handler for the form's submit event. The event handler should use an [XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) call](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call) to submit the form, update the button text, and cancel the form data submission. Something like this:

```
var myFormEl = document.getElementById("myForm");
myFormEl.onsubmit = function() {
    var submitButtonEl = myFormEl.childNodes[4];
    var message = myFormEl.childNodes[2].value;

    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("POST", "submit.php", true);
    xhReq.onreadystatechange = function() { // this request is async
        if (xhReq.readyState != 4)  { return; }
        // there should be some error-checking here
        submitButtonEl.textContent = "Send";
        alert("Your message has been submit");
    };

    var reqBody = "message="+encodeURIComponent(message);

    xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", reqBody.length);

    if(submitButtonEl.textContent) {
        submitButtonEl.textContent = "Please wait...";
    }
    else {
        submitButtonEl.innerText = "Please wait..."; // for different browsers
    }
    xhReq.send(reqBody);

    return false; // cancel the form submission
};
```

An important point is that doing it this way - using a button and a JavaScript event handler that cancels the form submission - will degrade gracefully; if JavaScript is disabled - or if the JavaScript fails in some way - an old-fashioned form submission will still work.

You can [see it in action](http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/stack-overflow/12749340/index.html) on my web site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input everyone. I did a little more research and managed to find a very simple solution that fits my needs. I used CSS to style my submit button to look like my other links and dropped the hyperlink tags and js submit function in favor of an actual submit button. I added some code to change the text value to "Please Wait" when the form is submitted and it works quite well.

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send" onClick="this.value = 'Please Wait';">
```

The only caveat is if the user happens to click the browser's back button after the form is successfully submitted, the submit button still says "Please Wait", but I can live with that.

BTW, I dropped the Macromedia form validation in favor of PHP validation script. Its not "live" like a javascript or jquery validation would be, but it works.